# How can I close the Cider stack trace buffer

Tags: emacs, clojure, cider

When evaluating an expression in the Cider REPL buffer a stack trace buffer appears in one of the other windows when an exception is thrown. Is there a way to dismiss the stack trace buffer other than killing the buffer?

When I navigate to a line of code from the stack trace buffer the buffer is dismissed but when evaluating something like `(first 1)` in the REPL there is no line in the stack trace that will point to any of my code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply press **q** and the stack trace will be hidden. Btw if you want to look at it later, you can still open it by switching to the *cider-error* buffer.